# Keeping Retrieved data in Griview from Another Gridview

Tags: c#, sql, gridview

The issue is I am using 2 gridviews on two different forms; the first one is to display items from a database and it working fine. When I select a row and click a button, the row will go to gridview #2 on the second form "Shopping Cart Form" I will display the row, but when I close the form or when I select another row from gridview #1 and want to retrieve it the first row that has been retrieved will be replaced by the new select row! how i can keep all the select item in gridview 2?

Here is the code for Grid View 1

```
    private void Buyer_Main_Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-CJGIQ74;Initial Catalog=Items;Integrated Security=True");

        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM list", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        adp.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
        {
            int n = Gridview.Rows.Add();
            Gridview.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item[0].ToString();
            Gridview.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item["Name"].ToString();
            Gridview.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item["Price"].ToString();
            Gridview.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item["Quantity"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

The code of the button to retrieve items to Gridview 2

```
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         Checkout datagrid = new Checkout(Gridview.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
             Gridview.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
             Gridview.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
             Gridview.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
         datagrid.Show();
    }
```

GridView 2 to display retrieved items

```
    public Checkout(string ID, string name, string price , string quantity)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = ID;
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = name;
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = price;
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value = quantity;
    }
```

So basically I want to keep retrieved data in grid-view 2 so the user can select what he want to purchase and checkout the selected items. Also, can anyone help me about the quantity how can I select only one it will be subtracted from inventory or stock I have

Answer (score 0):

**First GridView**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvAll" runat="server"

AutoGenerateColumns = "false" Font-Names = "Arial"

Font-Size = "11pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor = "#C2D69B" 

HeaderStyle-BackColor = "green" AllowPaging ="true"  

OnPageIndexChanging = "OnPaging" PageSize = "10" >

<Columns>

<asp:TemplateField>

    <HeaderTemplate>

      <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" onclick = "checkAll(this);"

        AutoPostBack = "true"  OnCheckedChanged = "CheckBox_CheckChanged"/>

    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>

      <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" onclick = "Check_Click(this)"

       AutoPostBack = "true"  OnCheckedChanged = "CheckBox_CheckChanged" />

    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:BoundField DataField = "CustomerID" HeaderText = "Customer ID"

 HtmlEncode = "false" />

<asp:BoundField DataField = "ContactName" HeaderText = "Contact Name"

HtmlEncode = "false" />

<asp:BoundField DataField = "City" HeaderText = "City"

HtmlEncode = "false" />

</Columns>

<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#C2D69B"  />

</asp:GridView>
```

**Secondary GridView**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSelected" runat="server"

AutoGenerateColumns = "false" Font-Names = "Arial"

Font-Size = "11pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor = "#C2D69B" 

HeaderStyle-BackColor = "green" EmptyDataText = "No Records Selected"  >

<Columns>

   <asp:BoundField DataField = "CustomerID" HeaderText = "Customer ID" />

   <asp:BoundField DataField = "ContactName" HeaderText = "Contact Name" />

   <asp:BoundField DataField = "City" HeaderText = "City" />

 </Columns>

</asp:GridView>


private void BindGridone()

{

    string constr = ConfigurationManager

                .ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;

    string query = " select CustomerID, ContactName, City from customers";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    sda.Fill(dt);

    gvAll.DataSource = dt;

    gvAll.DataBind();

}
```

The GetData function simply retrieves the records for which the user has checked the checkbox, adds them to a DataTable and then saves the DataTable to ViewState

```
private void GetData()

{

    DataTable dt;

    if (ViewState["SelectedRecords"] != null)

        dt = (DataTable)ViewState["SelectedRecords"];

    else

        dt = CreateDataTable();

    CheckBox chkAll = (CheckBox)gvAll.HeaderRow

                        .Cells[0].FindControl("chkAll");

    for (int i = 0; i < gvAll.Rows.Count; i++)

    {

        if (chkAll.Checked)

        {

            dt = AddRow(gvAll.Rows[i], dt);

        }

        else

        {

            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvAll.Rows[i]

                            .Cells[0].FindControl("chk");

            if (chk.Checked)

            {

                dt = AddRow(gvAll.Rows[i], dt);

            }

            else

            {

                dt = RemoveRow(gvAll.Rows[i], dt);

            }

        }

    }

    ViewState["SelectedRecords"] = dt;    
}

private DataTable CreateDataTable()

{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add("CustomerID");

    dt.Columns.Add("ContactName");

    dt.Columns.Add("City");

    dt.AcceptChanges();

    return dt;

}

private DataTable AddRow(GridViewRow gvRow, DataTable dt)

{

    DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("CustomerID = '" + gvRow.Cells[1].Text + "'");

    if (dr.Length <= 0)

    {

        dt.Rows.Add();

        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["CustomerID"] = gvRow.Cells[1].Text;

        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["ContactName"] = gvRow.Cells[2].Text;

        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["City"] = gvRow.Cells[3].Text;

        dt.AcceptChanges();

    }

    return dt;

}

private DataTable RemoveRow(GridViewRow gvRow, DataTable dt)

{

    DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("CustomerID = '" + gvRow.Cells[1].Text + "'");

    if (dr.Length > 0)

    {

        dt.Rows.Remove(dr[0]);

        dt.AcceptChanges();

    }

    return dt;

}

protected void OnPaging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)

{

    GetData();

    gvAll.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

    BindGridone();

    SetData();

}

protected void CheckBox_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    GetData();

    SetData();

    BindGridtwo();

}

private void BindGridtwo()

{

    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["SelectedRecords"];

    gvSelected.DataSource = dt;

    gvSelected.DataBind();

}
```